# javascript var alerts but when used is undefined

Tags: javascript

This is weird. Check this out:

```
 for( var i = 0; i <= videos.length; i ++ ){

    alert(videos[i].id); // this works and alerts the correct number

    var foo = videos[i].id; // firebug says "videos[i] is undefined"

 }
```

There are 3 videos. In FF this alerts all 3 video id's then fails saying that videos[i] is undefined. No Idea, at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the `=` in your `for` loop condition.

```
for( var i = 0; i < videos.length; i ++ ){
    ...
}
```

With `<=`, you are iterating to the index, one larger than the actual index value of the `Array`, so you are iterating over an invalid index which returns `undefined`.

For example...

If you have `array('A','B','C')`, the length is `3`. Now, if you iterate to `3 <= i`, and include `0`, as arrays begin with in Javascript, you will actually loop 4 times, not three.

The index value of `A` is `0`, not `1`, so you need to stop BEFORE `i` is equal to the length, not continue until `i` is equal to the length, since the `0` index is essentially added to the total length for the looping, meaning 3+1. 4 loops over this array would be one too many, hence the `<` and not `<=`. You want to STOP before 4, not stop AFTER 4 but before 5.

Also, it is generally good practice to cache the length of the `Array`, because some browsers do not optimise it.

Comment: Because you're going one longer than the available array length. Array indices start with `0`, and by including the `=` on the loop test, you're going one element too far. It just needs to be less than the length, not equal to.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: You forgot to say "please". `3` elements. Indexes: `0`, `1`, `2`.

Comment: @Fresheyeball see my answer for the explanation

Comment: *one larger than the size of the `Array`* could be confusing imo. You are right and I know how you mean it, but one could say that `i` will be `3` and the size of the array is `3`... but maybe I'm just too nitpicky now... should go to sleep ;) Good night! (and good day to the other side of the world :))

Comment: @alex - I would quibble with this, since the OP is not really *iterating the index one larger than the `length` of the `Array`*. In reality, the OP is actually iterating **TO** the length, which is the problem, since the origin index is `0`, not `1`. I know what you mean but your explanation is confusing to the uninitiated.

Comment: @alex - I'm just happy to know it doesn't only happen to me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing `i <= videos.length`, you are reading one past the end of the `videos` array.  Javascript arrays are zero-indexed, so you will usually want to iterate up to length - 1.

Instead, try:

```
for( var i = 0; i < videos.length; i ++ ){
    alert(videos[i].id); // this works and alerts the correct number
    var foo = videos[i].id; // firebug says "videos[i] is undefined"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the "<=" to "<" in the for loop.  It should fix the problem.

The problem is that you have only three items in the array.  You begin by addressing the first item with 0.  This means that 2 is the last valid index.  When the code tries to access index 3, it fails.  (That failure point would be at the 4th time through the loop, when the alert(...) tries to access a nonexistent 4th element (at position 3).